# Jquery Auto Expand Navigation

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need help.
what is wrong with my code.
The Sidebar navigation on the right needs to auto expand to the page the user is viewing.

Example: When User clicks the subpage Employment in the top navigation, The sidebar navigation should expands Employment

Website:
http://devsrver.com/

```
(function($){

            $(".dropdown-menu").click(function(){

                easy_sidebar_menu_widget_toggle( $(this) );
                console.log('A link was clicked!');

                //e.PreventDefault();

            });

            function easy_sidebar_menu_widget_toggle( $dis ){
                //alert("Clicked!");

                $dis.addClass('toggle__open');

            }

    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function

```
(function($){
  var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
  var sbmenu = $('.sidebar').find('a[href="'+pageURL+'"]');
  if(sbmenu.length) {
    sbmenu.closest('.menu-item').find('.easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler').addClass('toggle__open');
    sbmenu.closest('.sub-menu').show();
  }
})(jQuery);
```

You first need to get the current page url and find the element depends on the url. Then you just need to add the classes with respect to element. The code above does that.

Comment: how about the sub sub menu ?

Comment: @vince In that case just replace `closest` with the `parents`.

Comment: Thanks so much! @CodeThing